# c# Show and update progress bar when form is closing

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have a C# Windows Forms application that uses a third-party control that takes a long time to exit.

My _`FormClosing()` event contains something like this...

```
if (Thing != null && Thing.IsOpened)
{
    Thing.Exit(); //<-----THIS TAKES AGES TO COMPLETE and blocks the UI thread
}
```

I'd like to show a simple progress bar to show the user that the program has not crashed while Thing.Exit() executes.

I've tried updating a simple progress bar on the main form UI form with a BackgroundWorker thread but it does not show any update because (I assume) the form is shutting down.

I've tried launching a non-modal form just before the call to .Exit() but, again, I can't get it to show any update.

Anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Comment: The closing takes place on the UI thread, so the UI thread cannot update a `ProgressBar`. You could display a dialogue containing a `ProgressBar` on another thread, but then it won't be modal to the form that's closing.

Comment: You can display progress bar only if the Thing.Exit() can be called from another thread, otherwise the bar could not be updated. You can also hide the form when closing the app, so that the user can't see that it takes a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
As  Jiri Volejnik   says, I'll just hide the window as the form exits and let it close in the background.